# Error D8003: missing source filename and CMap

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working on a C++ solution. It builds and runs just fine on my main computer, but transferring it to a different computer results in those build errors:

> Error D8003: missing source filename in cl
>
> Error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<' at the declaration of a CMap in the header file.

Could someone direct me to the possible causes of this?

Comment: Do the computers have the same compiler?

Comment: How can I verify this?

Comment: What do you mean with verify? Don't you have access to the computers to compile?

Comment: Sorry, I mean how can I make sure both computers have the same compiler?

Comment: Install the same version of VS on both. That's it

Comment: Install the same compiler?

Comment: Both computers have the same compiler

Comment: Show us the code. So we can help you out.

Comment: WHile googling "D8003"  I stubled on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f40706e5-854c-4ec8-8346-7fe5e5621749/get-error-cl-command-line-error-d8003-missing-source-filename-when-trying-to-compile-the-c?forum=msbuild).

Comment: Is the path name longer than 260?

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that you need to have `#include <afxtempl.h>` in your src/header file.

Comment: That took care of the error C2143 but not the D8003. What's also strange is that the include wasn't needed when I compiled from my main computer.

Comment: Check your preprocessor definitions you could have accidentally put an unclosed double quote into the preprocessor definitions.